# (python) Youtube-dl Connection Error Handling

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, youtube-dl

I am running a script to download videos using youtube-dl in python

```
def dl_videos():
    while True:
        try:
            while True:
                ydl_opts = {
                    'ignoreerrors': 'True',
                    'download_archive': 'archive',
                    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                    'outtmpl': 'mp3downloads/%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                    'postprocessors': [{
                        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                        'preferredquality': '193',
                    }],
                }
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    with open ('PlaylistOnly', 'r') as r:
                        d = r.readlines()
                        for line in d:
                            ydl.download([line])
                time.sleep(24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)

        except(FileNotFoundError):
            time.sleep(5)
            continue

dl_videos()
```

however, I want this script to handle connection drops. so when I cut the connection in the middle of the program,  it is put to a complete hault with this error:
`[0;31mERROR:[0m Unable to download webpage: <urlopen error [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution> (caused by URLError(gaierror(-3, 'Temporary failure in name resolution')))`

Note: error only arrises during a certain point of youtube-dl's process if  online connection in lost

I would like the program to wait a little while with time then retry the module but i'm not sure how to handle this error at all. Idk if this is a specific error type i can handle with an exception. Any help appreciated

-Edit-
(solution)

```
def dl_videos():
    while True:
        try:
            while True:
                ydl_opts = {
                    'ignoreerrors': 'True',
                    'download_archive': 'archive',
                    'format': 'bestaudio/best',
                    'outtmpl': 'mp3downloads/%(playlist_title)s/%(title)s.%(ext)s',
                    'postprocessors': [{
                        'key': 'FFmpegExtractAudio',
                        'preferredcodec': 'mp3',
                        'preferredquality': '193',
                    }],
                }
                with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
                    with open ('PlaylistOnly', 'r') as r:
                        d = r.readlines()
                        for line in d:
                            ydl.download([line])
                #Checks if there's a connection to youtube.com, if there's none it loops back before the "freeze" which my dumb a didnt realize was just the next time.sleep function
                if assets.connect() == False:
                    time.sleep(10)
                    continue
                time.sleep(24.0 * 60.0 * 60.0)

        except(FileNotFoundError):
            time.sleep(5)
            continue

dl_videos()
```

Comment: Suggestion: you don't need to do 
`d = r.readlines()
for line in d:
    ydl.download([line])`
Instead, you can do `ydl.download(r.readlines())`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try updating youtube-dl

Anytime I have run into odd connection issues with it, it was resolved by updating it.

Also, see
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/618
https://github.com/ytdl-org/youtube-dl/issues/7586

Also, if you are trying to download many links at the same time, maybe try breaking it up into smaller chunks. Is it the same link that has the problem each time? Are some downloaded successfully?

/// EDIT

I understand your question better now that you have edited.
For a basic try and except solution you could just

```py
for line in d:
    try:
        ydl.download([line])
    except:
        print(f"error with {line}")
```

Comment: Oh i don't mean the issue is the connection randomly cuts out, Im cutting out the internet to test the script so i can write it to handle any actual connection drops.

however, when it does drop, the program gets this error. i'm trying to handle that. ill try to clarify in the post better

Comment: i'm srry, first couple of tests it seemed like it worked, but i was wrong. If the connection is lost in the middle of downloading a playlist, it gives the error, but if connection is lost inbetween downloading playlists, theres no error at all.

Comment: I just noticed that on line 3 in your code there is a try statement but no corresponding except. Maybe fix that and then add in a few more try except clauses at different points in the code to try and catch the errors. Also, you can import time, and then time.sleep(60) to wait for a minute, for example.

Comment: Oh thats my bad, I had a exception for it i forgot to add here. Edited it in. But anyways I  finally realized where I was having the issue. I misunderstood it "freezing" for my time.sleep function that goes on for a day...

But anyways I managed to take care of the issue by adding a if and continue loop with a network checking module before the time.sleep, and atm its fixed. But regardless i appreciate you taking the time to help out!